# MailChimp v3.0 API integrations in C#/.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

What are the best MailChimp v3.0 Api integrations int C#/.Net.

I cannot find anything good. I was using PerceptiveMCAPI but this one is really obsolete and doesn't look like it support new v3.0 API.

I now need to upgrade my code to use v3.0 API but it doesn't look possible with PerceptiveMCAPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [**MailChimp.Net**](https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net) wrapper. Its a MailChimp API 3.0 Wrapper